# Формула Беллара

Tags: c#, математика

есть формула Беллара которая должна возвращать n-й разряд числа пи в двоичном представлении:

[image: Формула]

и есть мой с# код:

```
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Введите нужный разряд ");
    double n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    double result = 0;
    double index = 0;

    do {
        result += (Math.Pow(-1, index) / Math.Pow(2, 10 * index)) *
                    (-(Math.Pow(2, 5) / (4 * index + 1)) -
                    1 / (4 * index + 3) +
                    (Math.Pow(2, 8) / (10 * index + 1)) -
                    (Math.Pow(2, 6) / (10 * index + 3)) -
                    (Math.Pow(2, 2) / (10 * index + 5)) -
                    (Math.Pow(2, 2) / (10 * index + 7)) +
                    1 / (10 * index + 9)
                    );
        ++index;
    } while (index < n);

    Console.WriteLine((1.0 / Math.Pow(2, 6)) * result);
}
```

возвращающий это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста ошибку

Comment: Давайте так.  А вы ручками подставили, что должно получиться? В чём вы считаете есть ошибка? Предполагаю, что алгоритм возвращает число, которое до n-ного знака точно правильное, а дальше уже не факт.

Comment: @Trymount - под  (n-й разряд числа пи в двоичном представлении), я понимаю к примеру сотое число в этой последовательности , в двоичном коде

Comment: для того, чтобы получить в ответе двоичный код, видимо считать нужно в двоичной системе

Comment: @Trymount - извините может я серьезно не понял. И получаю ответ точный до n-ого знака. Тогда мне нужен свой тип данных, для того чтобы вывести на 100 знаков?

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете смысл формулы. Та переменная n, которая в ней упоминается, не имеет ничего общего с номером разряда.

Comment: @PavelMayorov можете пожалуйста объяснить?

Comment: от n (числа слагаемых) зависит точность полученного значения Pi и ничего более, двоичные разряды тут ни причем. На ее основе можно вычислить нужный разряд числа Pi, но сама формула предназначена для вычисления самого Pi, к слову, при n=5 она выдает результат равный константе `Math.PI`, с точностью до последнего знака константы, а не самого Pi, разумеется. Про метод вычисления нужных разрядов лучше почитайте у автора http://bellard.org/pi/pi_n2/pi_n2.html